# Can I obtain terrain info from location API in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, here-api

To explain the question from the title. I want to get information such as if user is in the city, forest, how far he is from river/lake/sea (or even in general how far he is from water). It doesn't have to be super precise.

If it's not possible with standard SDK is there any other library that can help me get such info about current location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Check for Water**

You could fudge this with such techniques as making a `ReverseGeocodeQuery` and checking the country field is filled  in the first entry returned and distance to the nearest result, however this would also fail in underpopulated areas. An alternative would be to use the places API and check for the nearest place in the `underwater` category.

A better technique would be to build your own binary black-and-white minimap based on pixel analysis of map tiles from the [Map Tile API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile). The Map Tile API is based on the normalised mercator projection which means that the whole globe is one square at zoom 0, 2x2 at zoom 1, 4x4 at zoom 2 etc. Therefore if you check the color of the top left corner of a tile (and its blue) you can be certain that the 4 pixels below it at the next zoom level will also be blue. This can be used to define a "water" tile:

Your final map will look something like this:

[image: Ocean]

White pixel in mini-map = blue pixel in top right corner of map tile at zoom 10. Each tile is 13 km wide. Use a bigger map and higher zoom level to get more accuracy. Store this on the device.

Now all you need to do is check whether the pixel representing map tile at your input lat/long is black or white. Obviously each pixel here could be encoded as an individual bit and you could use a bit mask so you wouldn't need to take up much memory.

The tiles you would need to analyze are as follows:

[http://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/**basetile**/newest/terrain.day/**zoom**/**column**/**row**/128/png8?app_id=**AppID**&app_code=**AppCode**](http://1.aerial.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/basetile/newest/terrain.day/9/261/169/128/png8?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

[image]

**2) Check for Urban Area**

Again you could fudge this with such techniques as making a `ReverseGeocodeQuery` and checking the city field is filled  in the first entry returned and distance to the nearest 
point. The question is what do you consider to be an urban area?  Maybe the right technique here would be to look at road density - take this tile of Chicago for example:

[http://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/**basetile**/newest/normal.day.grey/**zoom**/**column**/**row**/128/png8?app_id=**AppID**&app_code=**AppCode**](http://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/basetile/newest/normal.day.grey/8/65/95/256/png8?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

[image]

It is fairly obvious that the average color of the top half of the tile will be "greyer" than the bottom half. You could analyze the average pixel over a larger area to make your bit mask.

The final result will look something like this:

[image]

White pixel in mini-map = urban area. The projection is wrong for this image, but you'll get the idea.

**3) Check for Forest.**

This could be a "green pixel" check on the ordinary base map tiles:
[http://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/xbasetile/newest/normal.day//**zoom**/**column**/**row**/128/png8?app_id=**AppID**&app_code=**AppCode**](http://1.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/xbasetile/newest/normal.day/5/8/11/256/png8?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg)

[image]

You'd need be careful with this forests don't appear to be consistently rendered over different zoom levels.

You can use the following calculation to find the `xTile` and `yTile` values from your `longitude` and `latitiude`. Obviously `zoom` will be fixed based on the size of your mini-map

```
latRad = lat * Math.PI / 180;
n = Math.pow(2, z);
xTile = n * ((lon + 180) / 360);
yTile = n * (1-(Math.log(Math.tan(latRad) + 1/Math.cos(latRad)) /
Math.PI)) / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate your effert, I am very grateful since the app I want to create is something I always wanted to do :). I actually had this idea in mind but wasn't sure if it's possible. Now I know it is. I will mark this as answer because it do what I want to do.